# jQuery.get() and returned html data: how to extract piece of codes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-get

Suppose that you can retrieve an HTML page through a call by using the `jQuery.get()` function, e.g. as follows:

```
$.get('xxx.php', 
        function(data) {
        //handle data, that is HTML code....
});
```

Is there any *jQuery* solution to extract elements (e.g. *div*, *ul* and so on) by the `data` variable?

PS: I don't believe that using `load()` to load *page fragments* is a good idea since I want to minimize the number of server requests.

Comment: The browser will cache repeated Ajax calls whenever possible.

Comment: So, Do you suggest to use `load()` instead of the `get()` function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.get('xxx.php', 
        function(data) {
        //handle data, that is HTML code....
        var pageDivs = $(data).find('div');
});
```

Just make the HTML returned a jquery object and you can use any DOM functions normally.

Comment: Uh, ok! It is very easy! Great Javascript library. Thanks!